# Why is "lievito madre" called so?

Tags: phrase-origin

I have a panettone and it’s made of "lievito madre". Why sourdough is called so? Why is there "mother" and no "dough"?

Comment: The translation of "lievito" is "yeast" - in Italian "lievito madre" defines the natural one (if I remember correctly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI09/00000405.jpg), a figurative usage of the word "mother" is

> Sostanza  o  prodotto  originario  dal  quale se ne traggono altri con successive lavorazioni

that is, "substance or original product from which others may be obtained through subsequent processing". This dictionary entry shows how "mother" with this sense has been used not only in the expression "lievito madre", as you can see in this quotation from the end of XVIII century by [Marco Lastri](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI_indice_autori/00165.jpg)

> Per ottener un buon effetto è necessario che il lievito « madre », volgarmente detto anco « fermento », sia estratto dalla pasta la quale in porzione è stata panificata tre o quattro volte

but also in other contexts:

> *M. Savonarola*, 46:  L’aqua  de  vita,  de  le  medexine calide  maestra  e  madre  è  chiamata,  e  ditta  de  la umana sanitade  optima  conservatrice  e  de  le  substanzie  restaura­trice. *D. Bartoli*,  9-28-3-73:  Tutti  i  mari  d’Oriente  non gli  avrebbono  vuoti  a’  piè  i  lor  gran  seni  pieni  di  conche madri  di  porpore  e  di  perle?   [...] *Malerba*,  1-61:  Per  ottenere  le  famose  diluizioni si  incomincia con  la  tintura-madre,  cioè  con  la  prima diluizione  di  un  grammo  della  sostanza  eletta  in  cento gocce di alcool.

I'm not an expert, but, as far as I know, "lievito madre", which is [also called](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lievito_naturale) "pasta madre" (literally "mother dough"), "pasta acida naturale" or "lievito naturale" is a fermented mixture of water and flour. As you can see at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sourdough), in English this mixture is called "starter", but it's also known as "mother" or with other names. Once it has been obtained, the volume of this mixture may be increased by periodic additions of flour and water. So, as explained in the dictionary, it's called "mother" in the sense that it's a product or substance from which you can obtain some more other by processing it in some way.

Answer (score 2):

The same definition is present also in English:

***[Mother yeast](http://www.ilariasperfectrecipes.com/whats-mother-yeast/)*** , also called natural yeast, acid yeast, sourdough, natural leavening, natural leavening dough, mother dough:

> is a mixture of flour and water acidified by a combination of yeast and lactic acid bacteria that start fermentation of bakery or pastry dough.